# Is there a standard procedure or regression model in marketing for explaining click rates on ads?

Tags: poisson-distribution, count-data

I have an experiment where people click on different ads online. My measure is click counts.

I end up finding that I should use models for count data such as Poisson, Quasi-Poisson, or Negative Binomial regression.

Is there a standard in marketing regarding what model should be used for click counts?

Thanks

Comment: in my data I have NO zeros. Maybe there is a recommended model with / without zero inflation and also one for low and one for high n...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Poisson regression and in more general form, Poisson process when data is following a Poisson distribution. In terms of Bayesian inference, you can make your own likelihood model, and then by conjugating your Poisson prior by likelihood, derive your posterior distribution.

Here I borrow an example from *glm* function in R:

```
 ## Dobson (1990) Page 93: Randomized Controlled Trial :
 counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
 outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
 treatment <- gl(3,3)
 print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
 glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family=poisson())
 anova(glm.D93)
 summary(glm.D93)
```

Also, some slides about Poission Rregression with some example are [here](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st572-larget/Spring2007/handouts24-2.pdf) and [here](http://www.statpower.net/Content/MLRM/Lecture%20Slides/PoissonRegression.pdf)